# Who is run out if both batsmen are out of their ground?

Tags: rules, cricket

[image]

Who is out in the attached picture, assuming non of the batters stop running or turn back to their original grounds? At the time of wicket is broken, both were out of their ground but they had not crossed.

Comment: This question is identical to one asked three years ago, and answered successfully. It even uses the exact same picture to demonstrate the situation.

Comment: Thanks @Nij. I was sure I'd seen this one before, but couldn't find the duplicate.

Comment: The identical question was difficult to locate as it was very poorly titled. I've edited the title to make it easier to find in future.

Answer (score 2):

This is covered by [Law 38, Section 3](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-38-run-out/). It states that the person run out shall be the one whose ground is closest to the end where the wicket is put down.

Both batsmen have left their ground, so [Law 29 section 2, clause C](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-29-batsman-out-of-his-ground/) states that "each ground belongs to whichever batsman is nearer to it" hence batsman B is out.